# Where to place methods for DataBinding controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Say I have a very simple .NET application with only a drop down list that's bound to a database table like

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDdlDropColor();
    }
    private void LoadDdlDropColor()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select color from Colors", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Color";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "color";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select color", "-1"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In terms of extensibility and best practice, is it OK to have data access being done outside of a `DataAccess` class?  Or would it be more professional to pass in multiple parameters i.e. the control, SqlCommand and, if needed, SqlParameters as parameters to a query called in the page load event?

Comment: "Is it OK?" is a subjective question. In the context of a "very simple" .NET app, then sure, why not. In the scope of a large app, of course not.

Comment: Can you do `DropDownList1.Items.Insert` after you have done data-binding? I'm not sure about asp.net, but in WinForms I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @dotNET You can indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple to moderately complex application, I'd by far prefer to use strongly typed DataSets (or EF for that matter) along with design-time binding support. It's fast, it's easy and it works. Making changes is also easier.

Comment: I wanted to learn as much under the covers stuff as I could, but it's looking like the Entity Framework just works and it would help me speed up my development.